# Could not automatically detect an ADB binary - (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I opened my emulator than this message popped up "Could not automatically detect an ADB binary".

There was the same question on someone else's on this platform but the answers were not satisfying in my case.
Some suggested that turn off "use detected abd location" from emulator and select path C:\Users\USERNAME.android\sdk..and the location of your abd.exe file.
but in my android folder there is no option of sdk.
What is the solution of this for me?
I am providing a snapshot of my .android folder.[snapshot of .android folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1oQ1.png)